# Can the "proxyUrl" in the "ionic.project" file be discovered in a release version on an Ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, proxy, ionic-framework, gulp

The question basically says in all. So I guess Im asking is the **ionic.project** file compiled into machine code? Or can the the url/path declared by the proxyUrl be discovered (or is it displayed/viewable) in the code when the app's build into an **.APK** or **.IPA** file?

I was also wondering the same for gulp files as **add-proxy** and **remove-proxy** can also be declared. From my understanding gulp files are only apart of the development environment. Am I correct to assume that gulp files are not bundled into the **.APK** or **.IPA** files and the **ionic.project** is but is converted into machine code?